# Django: Update Record before save

Tags: django, django-models

```
Model:

class Tester:
    test = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
    count = models.Integer()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
```

I need to change the status to 'D' every time I insert a new record for the same test.

I tried using Signals pre_save, but that function went into a loop. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal fucntion probably goes into an infinite loop because you save the same model's instances in that function, in turn each one triggering the signal function itself. With a little care you can prevent this from happenning:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Tester)
def tester_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk:
        # This means that a new record is being created. We need this check as you want to do the operation when a new entry is **inserted** into table
        Tester.objects.filter(test=instance.test).update(status='D')
```

or, with the post_save signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Tester)
def tester_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # This means that a new record has been created. We need this check as you want to do the operation when a new entry is **inserted** into table
        Tester.objects.filter(test=instance.test).update(status='D')
```

Important points here is. as we are using **update** method of a query set to update existing entries, those won't trigger signals, because they don't use the model's save method, so that signal method won't be triggered for other instances we update here. And even if it were to be triggered, as we are doing the update operation under a condition check (if a new instance is being created), signal methods for those other saves wouldn't do anything, hence they would not cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Override the save method of our Tester class:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if Tester.objects.filter(test=self.test).count()>0:
        self.status="D"
    else:
        self.status="A"
    super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Put this into the class definition of Tester.

Comment: else statement is actually not needed, as he got the default value ^_^